# What is Inetpub directory?

Tags: windows-xp

I found `Inetpub` directory in my *C:* in Windows XP Pro. What is this `Inetpub`? What is the use of this folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Inetpub` folder is related to the webserver [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services). It is usually the folder where the websites hosted by [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) are located.