# C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\ keeps growng and growing

Tags: ssd

What is it? Why is this so big? Can I savely delete it?

That's how my SSD grows so big by the way.

Comment: I'm sure you could have [searched the site](http://superuser.com/questions/454622/what-is-inetpub-directory) before asking. Do you use the web server in question?

Comment: I do not use IIS at all. It's a regular computer. Should I close this question?

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of the question above at least. Which version of Windows is this anyway? IIRC IIS has logging enabled by default. Are you absolutely sure IIS is not enabled under Windows Features? If it is, disable it and delete the logs.

Comment: You could use a tool like Microsoft (formerly Sysinternals) Process Explorer to identify the process which owns and writes to the logfile. Provided, the process or service is of no use to you, it could then be stopped and uninstalled. The "Autoruns" tool might be helpful for this 2nd step.

Comment: It's windows 7 64 bit